# CreateAsync doesn't save IdentityUser to database with derived IdentityUser

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

When Posting the following code works fine until it reaches the `_userManager.CreateAsync` method. No data is saved to the database.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _appDbContext;

    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public ValuesController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        AppUser user = new AppUser();
        user.Email = "email@mail.co.uk";
        user.FirstName = "mark";
        user.LastName = "Macneill";
        user.UserName = "Saints22";
        await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "P4$$word");

        return new OkObjectResult("Account created");

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Comment: Having never used UserManager myself I did some minimal reading and it looks as though UserManager is only responsible for adding info to the UserManager object but doesn't actually save the data to the database. I read something about passing through an IUserStore to the UserManager constructor which is what is actually responsible for saving the data to a data store.

Comment: if i am not mistaken your `UserManager<IdentityUser>` must be `UserManager<AppUser>`

Comment: here is a code where i manually used the user manager for some refrence. but your code seems fine. https://github.com/neville-nazerane/dotnet-csp/blob/master/DotnetCsp.Website/Controllers/AccountController.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be using the `IdentityUser` directly but instead a `AppUser` class. This might be a class extending `IdentityUser<>` or `IdentityUser`. I am not sure if you have the rest of your setup right, so here is the process:

If you have created a custom `AppUser` class, let's say you created it as follows:

```
class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
```

This would mean you have assigned the primary key as in `int`. However, if you extended `IdentityUser` instead, note that `IdentityUser` extends `IdentityUser<string>`, meaning your key is a string. Going ahead I am going to assume your key is `int`. If not, you can make the changes accordingly (change all `int`s to your key type.

In your startup class, you need to be adding the following to register this as your user class used for Identity

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Your `ApplicationDbContext` needs to be defined as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, IdentityRole<int>, int>
```

If you don't want to use `IdentityRole<int>` in the above two pieces of code, you can define a custom role class as follows:

```
public AppUserRole : IdentityRole<int>
```

Once you have these setup, you need to inject `UserManager<AppUser>` not `UserManager<IdentityUser>`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [neville-nazerane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991609/neville-nazerane)

I had IdentityUser in dependency injection and all I had to do was change IdentityUser to AppUser.

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: I would recommend adding your original startup code to your question

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue and found out that the issue was because of the password restrictions:

```
var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);
```

`result.Succeeded` turned out to be false.

To manage password restrictions you can update the policies as follows in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options => {
    // ---- customize your settings here...
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    // many different options to setup here!!!
});
```